# How to fix ImportError when importing Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, jupyter

I am trying to import tensorflow on a Jupyter notebook and it gives the error described below.

It happened after running  `!pip install -q tf-nightly`  by mistake.

I tried reinstalling conda and tensorflow several times but keeps showing the same error every time as run: import tensorflow as tf

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

SystemError: <class '_frozen_importlib._ModuleLockManager'> returned a result with an error set

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
```

Comment: can you try upgrading numpy, `pip install --upgrade numpy`

Comment: thanks it seems to have worked! Although I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling numpy. Upgrading it was the key. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Please try to upgrade numpy.

You can use the following command which worked fine for me.

**pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.17 numpy==1.14.5**